# Problema con NavigationLink en SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Cuando presiono el botón de comentario me lleva a una vista por medio de un NavigationLink y al volver me da este mensaje en la consola **Trying to pop to a missing destination at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Monoceros_Sim/Monoceros-39.4.3/UIKit/UIKitNavigationBridge.swift:390**  y al intentar de nuevo presionar el botón ya no pasa nada. Agradeceria su ayuda!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el PostCardView

```
NavigationLink(destination: CommentView()){
                HStack{

                Image(systemName: "bubble.right").resizable().frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                Text("10 Comentarios")

                }
            }
```

En el ContentView
NavigationView {

```
        TabView {
            HomeView()
                .tabItem({
                    Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                        .font(.title)
                })
            Text("Perfil")
                .tabItem({
                    Image(systemName: "person.circle")
                        .font(.title)
                })
        }.accentColor(.red)
            .navigationBarTitle("infoFiuna", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {

            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            }))
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
```

En el HomeView

```
ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false){
        VStack {


            ForEach(0..<8) {_ in

                PostCardView(user: "", image: "", id: "")
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: podrias agregar el codigo de lo que estas intentando?

Comment: Ahi tienes los códigos

Comment: Probando en un dispositivo real funciona muy bien solo es problema del simulador de iOS

Answer (score 0):

quizás te sirva esto que vi por aquí, dicen que es un poco el tiempo de refresco de las vistas
 [Pregunta parecida en StackOverflow English](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58404725/why-does-my-swiftui-app-crash-when-navigating-backwards-after-placing-a-navigat)

Comment: Se comenta que fue solucionado en iOS 13.3!